# Elance closes my account

Tags: freelance-websites

I am working as full time freelancer since 2013 as mobile app developer.
I mostly work on Upwork,Elance and couple of other sites.

Recently Elance closes my account even though i have 5 star ratings on all projects.
Most of my projects are long term so taking much time to complete.

I talked to the support but they always mentioned my low client satisfaction but how its a low client satisfaction if i have 5 star ratings on all projects.

Also i am not able to withdraw my account balance as well.

This is the email i received earlier.

[image]

What should i do now ? Thanks

Comment: Hey Johnny, you'll want to talk with Elance about this. We don't do support for third party sites.  Also, you may need to consult a lawyer if you can't find a resolution. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elance "cleaned up" their database the lazy way. Lot of people got wiped from Elance for apparently no reason at all, it has nothing to do with your rating, verified or not, so don't worry; but there's nothing you can do about it, it moved to Upwork for good.

For your issue with the customer support and getting your balance back, you might need to try contacting them by posting on their Facebook page if emails don't work.

**One thing that might work even better is to simply fill a complaint at the BBB** (http://www.bbb.org/losangelessiliconvalley/business-reviews/internet-services/upwork-in-mountain-view-ca-213440). Elance/Upwork is located in USA and usually things get fixed quickly when you can go through the Better Business Bureau.

Make sure to fill your complain with the details and proofs that there was a balance left if possible. I'm quite sure you'll get quicker responses to your issue using the BBB than trying to contact Elance through their customer support.